# No servers available for service: item-service : Post enable HTTPS on Api-Gateway in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, https, microservices, api-gateway

I have developed the Micro Service application with all services (Spring Boot)  like api-gwateway , service-discovery, cloud-config , item-service and all. I just enabled the https in api-gateway and able to access the rest service on api-gateway.
But while request re-rout to other service (Item or User service) then unable to call and it give 503 error as service unavailable.
API-Gateway internally call item service to get data.

Request :
Get : https://localhost:9191/api/item/

Response :
{
"timestamp": "2022-08-01T07:27:41.373+00:00",
"path": "/api/item/",
"status": 503,
"error": "Service Unavailable",
"requestId": "ccdc0886-4"
}

Please see below configuration:

- application.yaml

server:
port: 9191
ssl:
key-alias: spring-https
key-store: classpath:apigateway.jks
key-store-type: JKS
key-password: p***
enabled: true

spring:
application:
name: api-gateway
cloud:
gateway:
default-filters:
- DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
globalcors:
corsConfigurations:
'[/api/**]':
allowedOrigins: "*"
allowedMethods: "*"
allowedHeaders: "*"
routes:
- id: item-service
uri: lb://item-service
predicates:
- Path=/api/item/**
- id: user-service
uri: lb://user-service
predicates:
- Path=/api/user/**
httpclient:
ssl:
use-insecure-trust-manager: true
connect-timeout: 1000
response-timeout: 15s
config:
enabled: true
label: dev
config:
import: configserver:http://localhost:8888

management:
endpoints:
web:
exposure:
include: health
endpoint:
health:
show-details: always
gateway:
enabled: true

Comment: Issue is resolved post re-correct the rout as below in application.yaml :      

                      
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=item-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:9001/api/item
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/item/**


spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=user-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=http://localhost:9002/api/user
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/api/user/**

Comment: Solution# 2 - This is better as above solution will kill load balancer  feature in api-gateway. Hence just add below property in application.xml file in api-gateway.

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost